# Qt ActiveX "Unknown error"

Tags: qt, com, activex

I'm working on integrating T-Cube motor controller (http://www.thorlabs.de/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=2419) into the software based on Qt-4.8.1 package. Due to there is no manual or any sort of tutorial how to retrieve ActiveX object and how to call methods I did the following.

1) Looked through Windows registry looking for words similar to motor controller name. Found a candidate with CLSID "{3CE35BF3-1E13-4D2C-8C0B-DEF6314420B3}".

2) Tried initializing it in the following way (code provided is shortened, all result checks are removed  in order to improve readability):

```
HRESULT h_result = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
pd->moto = new QAxObject();
initialized = moto->setControl( "{3CE35BF3-1E13-4D2C-8C0B-DEF6314420B3}" );
QString stri = browser->generateDocumentation();
obj->dynamicCall("SetHWSerialNum(int)", params);

QVariantList params;
params << 0;
params << 0.0;
int result = pd->moto->dynamicCall("GetPosition(int, double&)", params).toInt();
value = params[1].toFloat();


QVariantList params;
params << 0;
params << dist;
params << dist;
params << true;
int result = pd->moto->dynamicCall("MoveRelativeEx(int, double, double, bool)", params).toInt();
```

3) generateDocumentation() method gives perfect description of ~150 methods.

4) All dynamicCall() invocations cause "Error calling ...: Unknown error", where "..." is a first argument of dynamicCall() from the list generateDocumentation()'s given me.

5) If I insert into dynamicCall() any method which isn't presented in the documentation generated the output is different. So I suppose that methods in documentation generated really exist.

6) If I use #import directive and try calling directly avoiding QAxObject usage I see "mg17motor.tlh" file but none of interfaces described there contain any methods. So I can't use it directly as well. Is it normal?

I would be very much obliged for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the ActiveX object using the OLE viewer. Then search for something like
`APT..` or `MG..` under `all objects`. Then find the parameter `ProgID=MGMOTOR.MGMotorCtrl.1`.

Now in Qt don't use `QAxObject` but `QAxWidget`. Then you get something like:

```
QAxWidget* aptMotor;
QVariant chanID = QVariant(0);
aptMotor = new QAxWidget();
aptMotor->setControl("MGMOTOR.MGMotorCtrl.1");

//Nice html documentation on available functions
QFile file("out.html");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
QTextStream out(&file);
out << aptMotor->generateDocumentation();
file.close();

aptMotor->setProperty("HWSerialNum",QVariant(83853493));
aptMotor->dynamicCall("StartCtrl");

aptMotor->dynamicCall("EnableHWChannel(QVariant)",chanID);
QThread::sleep(1); // Give it time to enable the channel

double pos(0);
aptMotor->dynamicCall("SetAbsMovePos(QVariant,QVariant)",chanID,QVariant(pos));
aptMotor->dynamicCall("MoveAbsolute(QVariant,QVariant,QVariant)",chanID,0);

aptMotor->dynamicCall("StopCtrl");
```